# How to anti-alias raster data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, plugins

How can I anti-alias the edges of raster data like in the screenshot?

I tried gaussian blur, but that didn't work.

[image: raster data on satellite]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Layer properties, then Style. Under resampling set Zoomed in: Nearest neighbour to Cubic. Set Zoomed out: Nearest neighbor to Average. Set Oversampling to 4 or 5. Maybe this helps.