# Anti-alias raster layer by upscaling/ resampling

Tags: qgis, interpolation, resampling

Recently, I performed a VGA analysis using Depthmap X. I moved the date over using a Mapinfo file (vector) and rasterised the values to the associated pixelsize. The analysis was conducted at a 2m scale.
[image]

The raster looks as follows:
[image]

However, as you can see, the courseness of the analysis creates a very jagged pixelated edge. Therefore, I want to upscale the raster image while retaining some of the sharpness.

I have been trying several of the Grass Gis r.resamp methods, Saga resampling and Gaussian blur, but none of these create the result I am looking for. Is there a way to anti-alias this image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to anti-alias raster data in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170143/how-to-anti-alias-raster-data-in-qgis)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The raster is already very pixelated due to its 2 meter resolution. The other options make it look worse.

Comment: Is anything preventing you from rasterizing at a higher resolution from the start?

Comment: Yes, the vector data itself has a resolution of one pixel = 2 meters in this image and 3 meters in another. The thing is, computing this analysis took over 24 hours, increasing the resolution to 1m would require a full week and for the entire analysis it would take 3 weeks...